# vCenter Converter for vSphere 5.1: is there a non-Standalone version?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I thought for sure there was one that ran as a plugin with vCenter via the vSphere client.

Does this exist?  Google-fu seems to bring up the Standalone free version only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to my knowledge - just the Free or Enterprise edition of the Standalone Converter are available now. I don't think there's any real advantage in having it as a Plug-In.

There was, however, a way to P2V using the vSphere Client back in the ESX 3.5 days. This was called the `vMware Converter Enterprise Plugin` Is this what you're thinking of? It appears to have been discontinued, but I can't find exactly when.

Update: This actually appears to have only been discontinued with ESXi 5.0:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1012946

and here: http://communities.vmware.com/message/2144901

> VMware removed the Converter from vCenter Server and only provides it as the Standalone version. One of the reasons was to be able to provide a single unique version of the Converter and be able to provide updates independently of vCenter Server.

Comment: Excellent work, Danny boy.